Is this code using Awaitable correct?
I am upgrading my code from coroutines to using async-await and Awaitables on Unity 6. I have the following code of a spawner:
    void Start() {
        SpawnRoutine();
    }

    async void SpawnRoutine() {
        while (true) {
            GameObject newObject = Instantiate(prefabToSpawn.gameObject, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            await Awaitable.WaitForSecondsAsync(1);
        }
    }

The code works well - it spawns a new object every second. The reason I am not sure about it is that, in similar examples I found, I saw that the SpawnRoutine returns an Awaitable, whereas my routine returns void. My questions:

Is my code correct according to the best standards?

Can I be sure that the code would work on WebGL too, given that WebGL does not support multithreading?



Have you tried testing it in WebGL to find out?

@LudoProf Yes, it works on my computer (running in localhost). But in the past, similar code (using Task instead of Awaitable) did not work for me. So I want to be sure that it always works.

I'm not familiar enough with webgl to give a definitive answer but going from other languages, the fact you've declared the method async is usually enough for the compiler to know to wrap whatever the return type is in an awaitable

Summary
1. Is my code correct according to the best standards?
Not quite correct. This implementation doesn't handle exceptions properly and doesn't stop when object is disabled or destroyed.
The correct code is either this (stops execution when disabled):
CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

void OnEnable() {
    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    SpawnRoutine(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}

async void SpawnRoutine(CancellationToken token) {
    try {
        while (true) {
            Debug.Log("SpawnRoutine()");
            await Awaitable.WaitForSecondsAsync(1, token);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.LogException(e);
    }
    finally {
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
        _cancellationTokenSource = null;
    }
}

void OnDisable() => _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();

or this, if you want it to run when disabled:
void Start() => SpawnRoutine();

async void SpawnRoutine() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            Debug.Log("SpawnRoutine()");
            await Awaitable.WaitForSecondsAsync(1, destroyCancellationToken);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.LogException(e);
    }
}

Exception handling can also be moved to the level above, e.g.
async void Start() {
    try {
        await SpawnRoutine();
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.LogException(e);
    }
}

async Awaitable SpawnRoutine() {
    while (true) {
        Debug.Log("SpawnRoutine()");
        await Awaitable.WaitForSecondsAsync(1, destroyCancellationToken);
    }
}

Note that in this case SpawnRoutine is async Awaitable.
2. Can I be sure that the code would work on WebGL too, given that WebGL does not support multithreading?
Yes.

Explanation
async void vs async Awaitable
Not awaiting an async Awaitable results in hidden exceptions. Not awaiting an async void doesn't hide exceptions. So, at the first glance, async void seems better.
The problem is that this code:
void Start() {
    SpawnRoutine();
    Debug.Log("Start() end");
}

async void SpawnRoutine() {
    Debug.Log("SpawnRoutine()");
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Test Exception");
}

will result in the following output:
SpawnRoutine()
Start() end
Test Exception

In other words, the exception that happened is delayed in the output.
Same will happen if you do it like this:
void Start() {
    try {
        SpawnRoutine();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.LogException(e);
    }

    Debug.Log("Start() end");
}

async void SpawnRoutine() {
    Debug.Log("SpawnRoutine()");
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Test Exception");
}

or even like this:
async void Start() {
    await SpawnRoutine();
}

async Awaitable SpawnRoutine() {
    Debug.Log("SpawnRoutine");
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Test Exception");
}

void Update() {
    // To see the order of operations, as Start will not end immediately
    Debug.Log("Update()");
}

But with this code:
async void Start() {
    try {
        await SpawnRoutine();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.LogException(e);
    }
}

async Awaitable SpawnRoutine() {
    Debug.Log("SpawnRoutine");
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Test Exception");
}

void Update() {
    // To see the order of operations, as Start will not end immediately
    Debug.Log("Update()");
}

the exception will be in its place.
SpawnRoutine()
Test Exception
Update()

So, formally, the best practice in terms of exception handling is this.
MonoBehaviours & cancellation
Unity documentation isn't fully explicit about that, but async/await's are automatically cancelled upon Play Mode exit. This results in a rumor that it is automatically cancelled upon object destruction which is simply wrong.
In other words, if you run this code
void Start() => SpawnRoutine();

async void SpawnRoutine() {
    while (true) {
       Debug.Log("SpawnRoutine()");
       await Awaitable.WaitForSecondsAsync(1);
    }
}

in Unity Editor, and then delete the object from the scene, this code will continue to run. Same applies to the code in build. What's more important, it will survive switching scenes.
In order to prevent this, you need to use the cancellation token. Luckily, Unity provides MonoBehaviour.destroyCancellationToken, so you can easily use it:
void Start() => SpawnRoutine();

async void SpawnRoutine() {
    while (true) {
       Debug.Log("SpawnRoutine()");
       await Awaitable.WaitForSecondsAsync(1, destroyCancellationToken);
    }
}

This will cancel the execution when object is destroyed, but also will throw an OperationCanceled exception. You can't do much about it as this is how CancellationToken was designed to behave, unfortunately.
So you have do suppress the exception by handling it:
async void SpawnRoutine() {
    try {
        while (true) {
           Debug.Log("SpawnRoutine()");
           await Awaitable.WaitForSecondsAsync(1, destroyCancellationToken);
        }
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException) { }
}

(Note that the exception handling happens within the void method. If you want it to happen the level above, you will need to make the method Awaitable.)
This will finally cancel the async method properly.
Another issue with not using the destroyCancellationToken is that if you enclose your code in
try {
    // Your code
}
finally {
    // Some cleanup
}

the code within finally block executes just fine when there is the destroyCancellationToken used, but doesn't execute at all when there is no token.
You should also use destroyCancellationToken for non-Awaitables (Task, ValueTask, UniTask), e.g.
async Awaitable Example() {
    await File.ReadAllBytesAsync("file.txt", destroyCancellationToken);
}

otherwise reading the file will not be canceled either.
If you need to cancel the method on just disabling the script, you need to create your own cancellation token as Unity doesn't provide one for this case.
But it provides Application.exitCancellationToken, which, according to the documentation, is required for background tasks (i.e. code running in a background thread) as otherwise the thread will continue to run after leaving  Play Mode.
WebGL & continuation
Problems with WebGL arise from the fact that WebGL doesn't support multithreading.
In .Net, the continuation of a Task (i.e. the code after await) could run on a different thread, which resulted in issues in WebGL.
But generally speaking, async/await isn't about multithreading, it is about asynchronous execution.
Implementations of async/await for Unity (UniTask and Awaitable) were created with the main thread in mind. You have to launch/switch threads explicitly to have a separate one. Though be careful as this might not be true if you await some third-party code, it can run a thread internally.
In addition, even the .Net Tasks could be safe to use in WebGL now, beginning with the version of Unity that implemented proper synchronization context, limiting the continuation to the launching thread. But note that I can't guarantee that, it is just a logical assumption.
UniTask
Unity Awaitable is a subset of UniTask with minor differences. This is probably not quite important for this particular use case - replacing the coroutines - but UniTask offers more functionality, WhenAny and WhenAll in particular. So I should probably still advice to use UniTask instead of Awaitable for general-purpose async programming.

Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I have to study it in depth.
